# How to render only the 3rd object from an array react

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here. I have a component which gets an array of objects in JSON format and saves it into the state.

I am now unsure how I can render the name/description of only the 3rd object in the components render function.

I want to be able to only render the 1,2,3,4,5th object etc as well.

Any ideas?

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ishizaka-rfp3k - Demo

```
   return (
      <div className="App">
        {name1} // Object 1 name
        {description1} // Object 1 description
        {name2} // Object 2 name
        {description2} // Object 2 description
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you the basic idea, you can display the name of your 3rd component on your render like this:

```
render() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.profiles.map((item, index) => {
        return(
          index === 2 ? item.name : ""
        )         
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Array map

```
  render() {
    const { profiles } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          profiles.map(profile => (
            {profile.name}
            {profile.description}
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.profiles.map((data, i) => {
        return(
          i=== 2 ? (<p>{data.name}</p>) :(<p> </p>) 
        )         
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```